# How to upload an image and saved into the database?

Tags: java, spring

How to upload an image and saved into the database and that image should be shown on the user profile page? The image can be of any type jpg, jpeg and png. I am using JSP, jQuery and Spring MVC framework and Java and Spring data jpa.

I am not using servlet in my application. I am new to this field and not able to complete it.

Comment: Can you please show us the code which you have tried yet..

Comment: I am not able to pass that image file to controller. i got stuck there.

Comment: look for "multipart-post request" for image upload, "insert blob into db" to save the image, then create a controller, that will return the image-data from the db by some kind of image-id

Comment: but how will i able to save that image in db.

Comment: you can save it as a "blob". thats the data-type for byte-array

Comment: ok .. how can i pass that image to controller?

Comment: google "multipart-post-request", thats how you upload data to a controller

Comment: create a resource folder on server -> Upload image to that folder -> Take that path and save it into the database. Retrieve this path from the database and use it in your jsp.

Comment: I am able to save the image as blob in db. now I want to fetch that image and show that image on jsp.

Answer (score 0):

- You need a VARBINARY column to contain the image.  Open the file using an `InputStream`, load `byte[]`s from it, and write that into the column.
- You need another column to save the mime file type.  You can obtain the file type with `java.nio.file.Files.probeContentType( Path path )`
- In your response headers, you need to:

  - Use `setContentLength()` to set the length of the file.
  - Use `setContentType()` to set the mime image type.
- If your database offers a means to create an `InputStream` on a varbinary column, use it.  Otherwise, you need to read the contents of your varbinary column into a `byte[]`, and then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` on the `byte[]`.
- Finally, you need to construct a response entity using the constructor that accepts an input stream: `return new ResponseEntity(inputStream, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);`

Comment: you should use "blob" as the data-type, VARBINARY should only be used for "small" data(up to 65kb)

Comment: @JohnnyAW well, I'd be willing to correct my answer, but I think it depends on the RDBMS, and the OP has not mentioned which one they are using.